# How to derive a formula related to the Gauss sum

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $m$ induced by $\chi'$ modulo $m'$. We define 
$$
\tau(\chi):= \sum_{a(mod \ m)} \chi(a) e(a/m).
$$

Could someone please show me how to derive the formula:
$$
\tau(\chi) = \mu(m/m') \chi'(m/m') \tau(\chi')?
$$
Thank you very much!

PS By $e(z)$, I mean $e^{2 \pi i z}$ and $\mu$ is the Mobius function.
And the sum $\sum_{a (mod \ m)}$ means I am summing over all the residue class modulo $m$.

Comment: Is $e(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ or something like that? Also, is your summation over $a=0$ to $m-1$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Try to have a look at Davenport's "Multiplicative number theory", Chapter 5. It might help.

Comment: This is in chapter 9 of Montgomery and Vaughan.